Estimating correlated features in OLS regression
I am given decently large sample set of $y_{i,t}$’s and ${\beta}_{i,j,t}$’s from following rolling (in time $t$) OLS regression fitted by someone else and I want to estimate timeseries $x_{j,t}$ :
$y_{i,t}$ = $\sum_{j=1}^{m}({\beta}_{i,j,t} x_{j,t})$ + $\alpha_{i,t}$ + $\epsilon_{t}$
$i$ and $j$ varies from $1$ to $n$ and $1$ to $m$ respectively with $n>>m$
$t$ is time index
$y_{i,t}$ and $x_{j,t}$ can be visualized as a timeseries of $n$ stock returns and $m$ factor returns respectively.
$\beta_{i,j,t}$ can be visualized as a $n$ timeseries of $m$ factor exposures. Here, $\beta_{i=I,j=J,t=T}$ can be different from $\beta_{i=I,j=J,t=T+1}$ since it was estimated using a rolling timeseries regression equation above.
Given sample of $y_{i,t}$ and $\beta_{i,j,t}$, I want to estimate timeseries of $m$ factor returns, i.e., $x_{j,t}$’s (say $\hat{x}_{j,t}$’s). Assuming the author of the original model did a decent job in fitting the above model, am I right to estimate $\hat{x}_{j=J,t=T}$, i.e., factor return $x_J$ at any given time $T$ as follows:
$\hat{x}_{j=J,t=T}$ = $\frac{Cov({\beta}_{i,j=J,t=T}, y_{i,t=T})}{Var({\beta}_{i,j=J,t=T})}$
Would $\hat{x}_{j}$ be biased if I was told that $Corr(x_{p},x_{q}) \neq 0$ for all p, q, i.e., there is a multicollinearity in $x_j$. If this is biased then what is the best way to get $\hat{x}_{j, t}$?
One can safely assume that there is no scaling problem, i.e., $x$ and $y$ are on the same scale. However, they are fat tailed.
